# "I had no sooner returned than I turned on" vs. "I have no sooner returned than I turn on"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect, past-perfect

Context: As a teacher who loves writing, I am interested in posting messages on the twitter.

Which of the following options is correct? Please explain the reasoning.

> 1. I am so interested in posting messages on the twitter that everyday **I had no sooner returned** home **than I** immediately **turned on** the computer to write something.
> 2. I am so interested in posting messages on the twitter that everyday **I have no sooner returned** home **than I** immediately **turn on** the computer to write something.

Comment: Second is incorrect. Better overall: _everyday, immediately I return home, I turn on the computer_

Comment: It is "on Twitter". "On the twitter" immediately blows your cover.

Comment: side note: neither will fit on the Twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal sequence of tenses would require the first sentence to be written as:

> I **was** so interested in posting messages on Twitter that every day
>   I had no sooner returned home than I immediately turned on the
>   computer to write something.

The second sentence brings the events one stage forward in time, and uses the present perfect *have . . . returned* in place of the past perfect *had . . . returned*. What the present perfect does here is describe a present state resulting from an earlier event.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Deeply appreciate your answer. It's truly clear and instructive.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is quite natural (if not entirely correct). The second sentence has an oddity of tense. In the second sentence you have "I Have Turn", that is a pretty big no-no.

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, you're right. It's pretty bad. Serious issues of tense.

Answer (score 0):

**No sooner than I return home, I turn on the computer.**

It is an everyday occurrence, hence simple present tense.

Also,immediately is not needed with 'no sooner'.