# "Scarcely did/had she put down the phone when it rang again"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Which is correct:

> - Scarcely did she put down the phone when it rang again.
> - Scarcely had she put down the phone when it rang again.

My own take is that both are correct, but that "had she" indicates a connection between the phone ringing and the fact that it was put down.

My "adversary" believes that only "had she" (past perfect) is correct, because the putting down precedes a past event, ie the phone ringing.

Comment: Closely related: [“I had no sooner returned than I turned on” vs. “I have no sooner returned than I turn on”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141388/i-had-no-sooner-returned-than-i-turned-on-vs-i-have-no-sooner-returned-than)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that both sentences are correct, but their meanings are different. **Do** is used both for emphasis as in "I **do** believe you," and to indicate habitual or repeated action as in "I **do** take sugar in my tea." Anyone who has suffered through the recent U.S. election, on hearing the first sentence, would think: what! the (DNC,RNC) is calling back again. I think there is a second interpretation, which Edwin Ashworth would call "one-off:"  perhaps **did** is being used to emphasize immediacy. Here are two examples:
"No sooner did I get the news, than I petitioned the Lord Justice Clerk." (David Balfour, R.L. Stevenson)
"No sooner did he face her, than Miss Pross uttered a scream ..." (A tale of Two Cities, Charles Dickens)

Answer (score 1):

The following from [Perfectyourenglish.com](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/blog/common-mistakes-in-the-use-of-conjunctions/)

> After ‘scarcely’ and ‘no sooner’, we can use ‘had’ or ‘did’. The
>   patterns are different.
>
> Study the examples given below.
>
> *Scarcely had she finished one project when she started working on another.*
>
> OR
>
> *Scarcely did she finish one project when she started working on another.*

I'd say that the former almosts demands a semelfactive (one-off) interpretation, whereas the latter strongly suggests habitual practice. With your example, 'put' can be either base form or past participle, leading to the similar-looking variants. But I'd say that the habitual practice suggested by 'did' (the semelfactive interpretation *is* possible, but I'd say reflects an archaic usage) would be unexpected here.

Comment: My "adversary" believes that only "had she" (past perfect) is correct, because the putting down precedes a past event, ie the phone ringing. What is your take on this.

Comment: I've answered this in my last sentence. I wouldn't use 'did she' for a one-off rather than a repeated event. But it's not ungrammatical; PYE's second example has 'did she'  'preceding [what may be taken as a single] [inchoative] past event'.